# Is it possible to parse a string of fixed length in yacc/lex?

Tags: parsing, yacc, lexer

I have a file format something like this

```
...
{string_length} {binary_string}
...
```

example:

```
...
10 abcdefghij
...
```

Is this possible to parse using lexer/yacc? There is no null terminator for the string, so I'm at a loss of how to tokenize that.

I'm currently using ply's lexer and yacc for this

Comment: "There is no null terminator for the string", then what is the next character after `j` in your input file? Is that your input file a binary file?

Comment: @LeeDuhem the next character character is the start of another node with size:binary string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a regular expression, but you can certainly extract the lexeme. You're not specific about how the length is terminated; here, I'm assuming that it is terminated by a single space character. I'm also assuming that `yylval` has some appropriate `struct` type:

```
[[:digit:]]+" "  { unsigned long len = atol(yytext);
                   yylval.str = malloc(len);
                   yylval.len = len;
                   for (char *p = yylval.str; len; --len, ++p) {
                     int ch = input();
                     if (ch == EOF) { /* handle the lexical error */ }
                     *p = ch;
                   }
                   return BINARY_STRING;
                 }
```

There are other solutions (a start condition and a state variable for the count, for example), but I think the above is the simplest.